# Privileges page cites meta as meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges-page, mso-mse-split

Help Center > Privileges > [participate in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) says:

> Our meta naming convention is standard across all sites. The meta site
>   for this site resides at:
>
> http://meta.stackoverflow.com

The link should point to http://meta.stackexchange.com

Moreover, the following seems incorrect:

> The following applies to all per-site Metas except Stack Overflow. **You
>   do not need Stack Overflow reputation to post on its Meta, and your
>   rep on its Meta isn't tied to the parent site.**

Actually, quite a bit is wrong on the said page.

Comment: Actually, the issues on that page are deeper. The bit later on reading "The following applies to all per-site Metas except Stack Overflow. You do not need Stack Overflow reputation to post on its Meta, and your rep on its Meta isn't tied to the parent site." is now wrong on every SE site.

Comment: Yes, I saw that _too_.